# How can I exit [NSRunLoop runUntilDate]?

Tags: cocoa, macos, nsthread, nsrunloop

I am writing an application which has to communicate with a device connected via USB. The app sends and receives data in turns from the device on a fixed timing. All Rx/Tx happens in a separate thread because otherwise the UI would be blocked. The basic structure looks basically like this. (autorelease pools and stuff omitted)

```
-(void)comThread:(id)arg {
  while(state == kIsConnected) {
    // let timers run
    [runLoop runUntilDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
    // handle data
    if(rxTxState == kRx) {
      // do some stuff to pass data to upper layers
      rxTxState = kTx;
    }
    if(rxTxState == kTx) {
      // do some stuff to send data
      rxTimeoutTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimer....];
    }
  } 
}
```

After sending data, the app waits for either data to be received or the `rxTimeoutTimer` to fire which leads to retransmission of the packet. The rx-operation works since the underlying layers use async system calls and calls a rx-handler which look basically like this.

```
-(void)receiveData:(NSData*)data{
  [rxQueue addObject:data];
  [rxTimeoutTimer invalidate];  // cancel timeout
}
```

Is there an (easy) way to make the `[runLoop runUntilDate:]` exit from `receiveData:`? The Apple docs say that removing all timer sources does not guarantee the RunLoop to exit. I read something about calling `performSelector:onThread:...` but it either did not work or I did not get the point.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

```
CFRunLoopStop([runLoop getCFRunLoop]);
```

Comment: Or, without the 'runLoop' local variable:

CFRunLoopStop([[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] getCFRunLoop]);

Comment: @rpj: You use `CFRunLoopGetCurrent()` in that case :)

Answer (score 5):

The standard pattern is to run the runloop for some timeout period (e.g. 0.5 seconds), and then iterate until the task is accomplished:

```
while(state == kIsConnected) {
  while(!iterationDone) {
    [runLoop runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.5]];
    //do other stufff
  }
}

-(void)receiveData:(NSData*)data{
  [rxQueue addObject:data];
  [rxTimeoutTimer invalidate];  // cancel timeout
  iterationDone = YES;
}
```

Comment: The whole timeout is 0.5 seconds in my case. I would have to run the RunLoop for fractions of this time like 0.05 seconds. I wonder if it really has this resolution.

Comment: It really has this resolution.

Comment: The `-runMode:beforeDate:` method with a `distantFuture` argument might work too, since it processes one input source then returns, at which point the `while` condition would be checked and (if it's true) the run loop restarted.

Answer (score 0):

> CFRunLoopStop([runLoop getCFRunLoop]);
>   and
>   CancelPerformSelector

didnot work for me ,
See my Code for running [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]

```
timerUpdateLocation = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:[time intValue] target:self selector:@selector(startTrackingBg) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:timerUpdateLocation forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];
```

To Stop it I Just invalidate timer.

> [timerUpdateLocation invalidate];

Answer (score 0):

Do like this can exit. but it will exit after a few seconds.

```
 -(void)comThread:(id)arg {
      BOOL ret = YES;
      rxTimeoutTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimer....];
      while(ret) {
        // let timers run
        ret = [runLoop runUntilDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
      } 
    }
    -(void)receiveData:(NSData*)data{
      [rxQueue addObject:data];
      [rxTimeoutTimer invalidate];  // cancel timeout
      iterationDone = YES;
    }
```

the kennytm's answer seems right.